# Passing strings or properties to WPF Code Behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't figure out how to pass any properties or fields or data from my main application into the "Code Behind" of a WPF form.

I'm trying to write an application that lets the user edit some C# parameters from a WPF form following this example:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm

The example works well enough.  The only problem is I don't want to put all of my code in the "Code Behind" class of the form.   The program has to do other things, and it will have other forms.

But I can't figure out how to pass any info into the code behind.  I even created a public static string in my main application, but even that seems to be out of scope in the Code Behind of the WPF form.

(BTW - I've been dabbling in C# programming for quite a while, but I still don't understand a lot of the more abstract concepts like partial classes and such.)

Thanks for any help.

My main application is a Revit Macro.  Here is the main application code with the public static string:

````
using System;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace WPF2021Test
{
    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
    [Autodesk.Revit.DB.Macros.AddInId("5973D9EF-F3DA-494B-9992-5636CB0DB94C")]
    public partial class ThisApplication
    {
      ///Revit stuff left out
      public static string mycomment = "";
      public void Tutorial1()
        {
            UIDocument uidoc = this.ActiveUIDocument;
            Document doc = this.ActiveUIDocument.Document;
            View pview = uidoc.ActiveView;
            Window2 win2 = new Window2 ();
            win2.Show();
        }

}
}



    ```

And the code behind I tried:

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;


using System.Linq;


namespace WPF2021Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window2.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window2 : Window 
    {
        
        //The next line doesn't work
        Person person = new Person { Name = WPF2021Test.mycomment, Age = 26 };
        
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = person;
        }
        
         private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
         {
         string message = person.Name + " is " + person.Age; 
         MessageBox.Show(message); 
         }
         
    }
        
    public class Person { 
    
      private string nameValue;
        
      public string Name { 
         get { return nameValue; } 
         set { nameValue = value; } 
      } 
        
      private double ageValue; 
        
      public double Age { 
         get { return ageValue; } 
                
         set { 
            if (value != ageValue) { 
               ageValue = value; 
            } 
         } 
      } 
    }
        
}
````

Comment: What exactly is "main application" in this case? Could you please show your code?

Comment: It's actually a Revit Macro.   For example, here is the code with the public :  Hmmm.... can't figure out how to add code to a comment, and I can't find a way to reply.  I'll try to add the code to the original post.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the public static string?

Comment: I was trying to pass it to the code behind.

Comment: Pass? How? Again, you need to include code that demonstrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is, that you have decided to connect your View with the DataContext of "Person".

The question is what are you trying to do?
Why did you connect the DataContext with person and then you will use the code behind? that's doesn't seem to make sense.

Please provide some use case why you even want to connect with the code behind.